# Turning a single column of csv data into a new csv file with multiple columns

Tags: python, csv

I'm very new to python and was wondering how I might go about converting a single column csv into multiple columns in a new csv file. The script must iterate down the source csv column by steps of one with a sliding window of say 3 or any length window I wanted.

So, say source csv included numbers 1 to 10 in a single column, with a sliding window of 3 the output csv would be: 
Column 1 (1 to 3)
Column 2 (2 to 4)
Column 3 (3 to 5)
etc.

Apologies for being such a rookie. Any help on this (I'm sure easy) question would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have done and ask on where you are stuck.

Comment: All I've managed to do is load csv into a single column df with pandas. As I assume it's easier to go from there with manipulating the dataframe.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

Answer (score 0):

As you already started, you can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to accomplish what you want. Assuming the `test.csv` file is one column without header, you can use `header=None` to import the first line as a data row too. Then you need to create a new pandas [Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). Afterwards, you must iterate over your Dataframe using a step of 3 (which is what you specified). In the for loop, you must add the new columns to the new Dataframe. You can accomplish that selecting the first column of the `df` Dataframe (which is the only column available), and slicing your Dataframe using [.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), but in order to place your new column in the new Dataframe, you must reset your selection index using [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and dropping the old one.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

index = 1
for i in range(0, len(df), 3):
    new_df['Column' + str(index)] = df[0].iloc[i:i+3].reset_index(drop=True)
    index += 1

print(new_df)
```

This code results in the following dataframe:

```
    Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
0        1        4        7     10.0
1        2        5        8      NaN
2        3        6        9      NaN
```

For some reason, 10 appears to be a float pointing number. You might get around it using [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) function.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It's all starting to make more sense to me.